# To use winjs for hybrid android application in eclipse

Tags: cordova, winjs, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I build an hybrid application using winjs framework and Eclipse IDE? From where can I get the required js files for that? Any sample app link would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible. But I'm pretty you can use Eclipse to build an app (I use WinJS in Sublime Text a lot for webbased stuff).

The entire source for WinJS is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/winjs/winjs). You have to build it yourself though, which is pretty straight forward.

There are a lot of example on WinJS in the browser on [try.buildwinjs.com](http://try.buildwinjs.com/).